# Simplest way to publish over Zeroconf/Bonjour?

Tags: python, bonjour, zeroconf

I've got some apps I would like to make visible with zeroconf.

1. Is there an easy scriptable way to do this?
2. Is there anything that needs to be done by my network admin to enable this?

Python or sh would be preferrable.  OS-specific suggestions welcome for Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 2022-02-27: I'm not 100% sure anymore what I wrote is actually correct. I tried it recently and although it ran, I couldn't get the info back through `mdns` query; suggesting that mDNS is possibly more complex than expected..... To be continued.... And please leave a comment if this does/does not work for you.

---

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38870582/1207489) points you in the right direction, it seems that [python-zeroconf](https://github.com/jstasiak/python-zeroconf) (0.39.4) had some changes making the example above not work (for me) anymore.

Also I think a more minimal, self-contained, answer would be nice, so here goes:

```
from zeroconf import ServiceInfo, Zeroconf

PORT=8080

zeroconf = Zeroconf()
wsInfo = ServiceInfo('_http._tcp.local.',
                     "myhost._http._tcp.local.",
                     PORT, 0, 0, {"random_key": "1234", "answer": "42"})
zeroconf.register_service(wsInfo)

import time
time.sleep(1000);
```

Note that anything beyond `PORT` is optional for `ServiceInfo()`.

You can run multiple of these programs at the same time; they will all bind to the same UDP port without a problem.

Answer (score 11):

pybonjour doesn't seem to be actively maintained. I'm using [python-zeroconf](https://github.com/jstasiak/python-zeroconf).

```
pip install zeroconf
```

Here is an excerpt from a script I use to announce a [Twisted-Autobahn WebSocket](http://autobahn.ws/python/) to an iOS device:

```
from zeroconf import ServiceInfo, Zeroconf

class WebSocketManager(service.Service, object):
    ws_service_name = 'Verasonics WebSocket'
    wsPort = None
    wsInfo = None

    def __init__(self, factory, portCallback):
        factory.protocol = BroadcastServerProtocol
        self.factory = factory
        self.portCallback = portCallback
        self.zeroconf = Zeroconf()

    def privilegedStartService(self):
        self.wsPort = reactor.listenTCP(0, self.factory)
        port = self.wsPort.getHost().port

        fqdn = socket.gethostname()
        ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(fqdn)
        hostname = fqdn.split('.')[0]

        wsDesc = {'service': 'Verasonics Frame', 'version': '1.0.0'}
        self.wsInfo = ServiceInfo('_verasonics-ws._tcp.local.',
                                  hostname + ' ' + self.ws_service_name + '._verasonics-ws._tcp.local.',
                                  socket.inet_aton(ip_addr), port, 0, 0,
                                  wsDesc, hostname + '.local.')
        self.zeroconf.register_service(self.wsInfo)
        self.portCallback(port)

        return super(WebSocketManager, self).privilegedStartService()

    def stopService(self):
        self.zeroconf.unregister_service(self.wsInfo)

        self.wsPort.stopListening()
        return super(WebSocketManager , self).stopService()
```

Answer (score 10):

Or you can just use bash:

```
dns-sd -R <Name> <Type> <Domain> <Port> [<TXT>...]
```

This works by default on OS X.  For other *nixes, refer to the [avahi-publish](https://linux.die.net/man/1/avahi-publish) man page (which you may need to install via your preferred package manager).

Comment: @bjoernz I have updated my answer to reflect the linkrot.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend [pybonjour](http://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/).

Comment: Sounds good. Note it currently [doesn't support Python 3.x — see issue #5](http://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/issues/detail?id=5).

Answer (score 2):

Through the [Avahi Python bindings](http://avahi.org/wiki/Bindings), it's very easy.

Comment: I don't know unfortunately.

Comment: it is avahi only, which runs on Linux and most BSDs.